# How does the Windows version of notepad++ handle the line terminator?

Tags: notepad++

I am editing two files in the same folder.  Both of them are `Encode in UTF-8 without BOM`.

One of them when saved will always save as Windows CRLF end of lines.

The other will always save as LF only.  Even if I open it in notepad.exe and erase everything and create new lines, save it, the next time notepad++ saves it, LFs are used as line terminators.

When I turn on View Show all characters, pressing Enter in the first file will insert a CRLF.  In the second file, pressing Enter will insert LF.

How do I control the type of line terminators to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Edit > EOL Conversion, and select the format you prefer. This will convert all existing line terminators to the format you choose, and all future presses of the Enter key will result in the corresponding line terminator being input.

Note: I am not aware of a way to make the Enter key insert LF in a document where the rest of the line terminators are Windows-style CR LF (or vice versa: make Enter insert CR LF in a document where the rest of the line terminators are Unix-style LF) without converting all the line terminators via Edit > EOL Conversion.